# MySQL DATETIME - Change only the date

Tags: mysql

Starting with : 2011-01-17 09:30:00

Let's say I want to edit just the date with 2011-01-28

What is the most efficient way to end up with: 2011-01-28 09:30:00

Thanks!

For everyone saying Date_Add... that would require me to subtract the dates, then add the days.  Thats a possibility... but was looking to remove that first step, and just "replace" the date

Comment: Will the year always remain the same?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you really don't want to use date_add function, you can consider using this construction:

```
UPDATE table_name SET field_name = concat('2011-01-12 ', time(field_name))
```

Make sure to add a space after the date (**'2011-01-12`◯`'**).

Comment: Saved me some good stress. Works well with WHERE condition(s) too.

Answer (score 18):

To change it 5 days ahead:

```
UPDATE yourTableName
SET myDate1 = myDate1 + INTERVAL 5 DAY
WHERE myDate1 = dateIWantToChange
```

(you can use MONTH, YEAR, etc too)

Comment: For some reason, my answer wouldn't submit when i had the word "update" above spelled correctly. Weird.

Answer (score 3):

Probably, DATE_ADD is a good idea. [link text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Answer (score 2):

**Check Query**

```
 update yourtable set eventtime=replace(eventtime,substr(eventtime,1,10), '2013-07-17')  WHERE  `id`=4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add various components of a date to modify it using the Date_Add function. Check this out:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Answer (score 1):

### Going to use something like:

```
CONCAT('2011-01-28 ',DATE_FORMAT(original_timestamp, '%H:%i:%s'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Use:

```
UPDATE table_name set column_name= DATE_FORMAT(column_name,'%Y-%m-28 %H:%i-%s');
```