# MySQL - update the row's date and save the time

Tags: mysql

I want to update a row which has timestamp datatype named date_start. Here's an example:

```
 date_start = 2017-04-26 12:34:11
```

I want to update it, but to save the time, so it'll look like this:

```
 date_start = 2017-05-28 12:34:11
```

Any ideas? So far I tried extract method and concat method.

Best Regards..

Comment: Is the problem that you don't know how to use `UPDATE` query or what? Your statement that you tried to use extract and concat method make absolutely no sense whatsoever.

Comment: I do know how to use `UPDATE` query, but I do not know how to update the date only in a timestamp field.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL DATETIME - Change only the date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695117/mysql-datetime-change-only-the-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to update the date component of the timestamp while retaining the time component then you can build the updated timestamp using string concatenation with `TIME()`:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET date_start = CONCAT('2017-05-28 ', TIME(date_start))
WHERE <some condition>
```

## Demo

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the reply. This one turned the date_start field into 0000-00-00 00:00:00 .

Comment: No, this should not have happened.  Did you run my _exact_ query?

Comment: Yes. here is the query:
`UPDATE campaigns
SET date_start = CONCAT('2017-07-25 ', TIME(date_start))
WHERE id = 918`

Comment: It works for me in the demo.  Give me a reproducible example and I will look at it.